# Swift - Adding UserDefaults to NotificationCenter

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, nsuserdefaults, uicolor

I implemented a **NotificationCenter** whenever you tap on a specific **TableViewCell** to perform that notification inside another **ViewController**, for this example the other **ViewController** background colour turns pink which works fine, but my question is how do I save the state of the pink colour being the same inside that **ViewController** using **UserDefaults**?

**To clarify this much better:**

- **ViewController #2** contains the TableViewCell that performs the action when pressed
- **ViewController #1** is the view where the colour changes to Pink.

**What I want to achieve?**

Save the state of the pink colour in **ViewController #1** using **UserDefaults**

**ViewController #1 Code**

**- viewDidLoad**

```
override func viewDidLoad()
{
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(BrandTableViewController.testNotifcation(notification:)), name:NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "refresh"), object: nil);
}
```

**- TestNotification Function**

```
@objc func testNotifcation(notification: NSNotification) { 

    table.backgroundColor = UIColor.systemPink

    print("This is a message to say it is working")
}
```

**ViewController #2 Code**

**didSelectRowAt**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    if indexPath.row == 0
    {

        if traitCollection.userInterfaceStyle == .light
        {
            NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "refresh"), object: nil, userInfo: nil)
            self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
        else if traitCollection.userInterfaceStyle == .dark
        {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I didn't get "but my question is how do I save the state of the pink colour being the same" , do you want to save any `UIColor` in `UserDefaults` or what ???, can you please elaborate more or attach screenshot ???

Comment: Once the tableviewcell is pressed in the second view controller, the tableview within the first view controller is pink but save the state of the pink colour when I close and open the application, it is still pink. I have already stated this in this question under "What I want to achieve?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set color in `UserDefaults` when you notification method called. So, updated your code as follow in **ViewController1**:

```
@objc func testNotifcation(notification: NSNotification) { 

    table.backgroundColor = UIColor.systemPink

    let colorData = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: UIColor.systemPink)
    UserDefaults.standard.set(colorData, forKey: "savedColor")
    UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()

    print("This is a message to say it is working")
}
```

Then, In view did load, you need to add code to fetch saved color and set it as background. So update code in `viewDidLoad` in **ViewController1**.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(BrandTableViewController.testNotifcation(notification:)), name:NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "refresh"), object: nil);

    if let colorData = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "savedColor") as? Data,
        let savedColor = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: colorData) as? UIColor
    {
        table.backgroundColor = savedColor
    }
}
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: I am now getting a "Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Attempt to insert non-property list object <UIDynamicSystemColor: 0x600000dc2560; name = systemPinkColor> for key savedColor'" error

Comment: @Broski, Please check my updated answer, It will works.

Comment: Thank you for the updated code, it is now running perfectly but every time I close and reopen the application it does not save the Pink in the first view controller and goes back to default.

Comment: @Broski, If you had copy my code, than there was mistake in key, please change it to `savedColor` from `SavedColor`.

Answer (score 1):

**If you want to save `UIColor` in `UserDefaults` , you can not directly achieve that as `UserDefaults` can not save the value of type `UIColor` BUT I have achieved same thing but with different manner**

- First You have to create an `Array` of Rob values of the `UIColor` you want to save , then you can save that array in `UserDefaults` and use it anywhere

**For That Firstly you have to get rob values of your `UIColor`**

```
extension UIColor {

func rgb() -> (red:Int, green:Int, blue:Int, alpha:Int)? {
    var fRed : CGFloat = 0
    var fGreen : CGFloat = 0
    var fBlue : CGFloat = 0
    var fAlpha: CGFloat = 0
    if self.getRed(&fRed, green: &fGreen, blue: &fBlue, alpha: &fAlpha) {
        let iRed = Int(fRed * 255.0)
        let iGreen = Int(fGreen * 255.0)
        let iBlue = Int(fBlue * 255.0)
        let iAlpha = Int(fAlpha)

        let rgb = (iAlpha << 24) + (iRed << 16) + (iGreen << 8) + iBlue
        return (red:iRed, green:iGreen, blue:iBlue, alpha:iAlpha)
    } else {
        // Could not extract RGBA components:
        return nil
    }
}}
```

- With above `rob()` function you can get rob value of any `color` as below

  ```
  let currcol = YourColor.rgb()!
  let arrayOfRGB = [currcol.red , currcol.green , currcol.blue]
  UserDefaults.standard.set(arrayOfRGB, forKey: "rgbofcolor")
  ```
- That will save the `array` of rgb value of your desired color and then in any `ViewController` you can use it as below

  ```
   let preColor = UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "rgbofcolor") as? [Int]
   print("color RGB \n\(String(describing: preColor))\n")
   if preColor == nil
   {
   print("Color is not saved in Userdefaults")
   }
  else
  {

  let YourDesiredColor = UIColor(red: CGFloat(Double(preColor![0])/255.0), green: CGFloat(Double(preColor![1])/255.0), blue: CGFloat(Double(preColor![2])/255.0), alpha: 1)

  print("Color was saved successfully in UserDedaults")
  }
  ```

Hope it helps.....